Error in PyCharm: Package requirement 'Django==5.0.7' is not satisfied
I'm trying to set up a Django project in PyCharm, but I keep encountering the following error:
Package requirement 'Django==5.0.7' is not satisfied

I have already tried the following steps:

Ensured that Django==5.0.7 is listed in my requirements.txt file.
pip install -r requirements.txt
Verified that my virtual environment is activated

Despite these efforts, PyCharm still doesn't recognize the installed Django package.
Here are some additional details:

PyCharm version: 2023.3.2
Python version: 3.10.1
OS: Windows 10

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

use pip list to show the installed packages..!

Ensured that Django==5.0.7 is listed in my requirements.txt file. How did you ensure this?

Be sure the correct interpreter is selected for the project.
Bottom right of PyCharm, check the active interpreter:

If the interpreter is what you expect, then go to PyCharm settings -> Project -> Python interpreter, and check that Django 5.0.7 is actually installed. You should see something similar to:


The virtualenv in case of @Trenomarcus has the name back-end. It can be a name of your choice.
